# 'str' object has no attribute 'port'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing this code to create a chat application, but I am getting an Attribute error. Please help me solve it.

```
import socket
import sys
import time

## end of imports

## init

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
print(" server will start on host", host)

port = 8080
s.bind((host.port))
print("")
print("Server done binding to host and port successfully")
print("")

s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print(addr, "has connected to the server and is now online")
print("")
```

Comment: host.port doesn't look right to me... try s.bind((host, port))

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
s.bind((host.port))
```

You are trying to call an attribute named "port" on the object "host" but earlier in your code you set "host" to:

```
host = socket.gethostname()
```

which is simply returning a string... which doesn't have an attribute "port" just like the error says. The following is what you should change your line "s.bind((host.port))" to...

```
s.bind(port)
```